# AWS SES send mail from any address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Do I need to verify the email address to send the email via SDK?
I have verified domain:
[image]

and "Send a Test Email" from any address in this domain works perfectly.

But I see that to use SDK I need to verify email address:

> // Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
> // This address must be verified with Amazon SES.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-php.html

Is there any way to use SDK without verifying the email address?

Best,

Answer (score 3):

To use SES you must verify you have control of the domain you want to send the email from.

In order for SES to remain as a reputable source these checks will always need to be performed.

If you want to send from the whole domain you must have your account migrate from sandbox mode for that specific region.

This can only be done by contacting AWS support, who will then unlock the domain.

Take a look at [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If your domain is already verified thru SES, than you should be able to send emails from any email address on that domain no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to verify your domain or whole domain. Also you have to request to exit from sandboxmode.